# Split file based on a date field

Tags: text-processing, split

I have a file `abc.txt`. I need to grep the file on the date field which is present at 4<sup>th</sup> position in the text file. I need to split the file based on the date from 1<sup>st</sup> to 15<sup>th</sup> August the data need to be in one file and from 16<sup>th</sup> to 31<sup>st</sup>  August the data need to be in another file.

How can I do that?

```
a|b|c|08/01/2017|d
a|b|c|08/15/2017|d
a|b|c|08/16/2017|d
a|b|c|08/31/2017|d
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy job with `awk`:

```
awk -F'|' '{print >((substr($4,4,2)<=15)?"1-15Aug":"16-31Aug")}' infile
```

This is checking if the day of month in date was ‎≤15 in filed #4 it will write the lines into the file `1-15Aug` otherwise those will redirect to `16-31Aug` file using Ternary condition.

The output would be 2 files:

```
==> 1-15Aug <==
a|b|c|08/01/2017|d
a|b|c|08/15/2017|d

==> 16-31Aug <==
a|b|c|08/16/2017|d
a|b|c|08/31/2017|d
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -n -e '\#08/01/2017#,\#08/15/2017#w first.out' \
       -e '\#08/16/2017#,\#08/31/2017#w second.out' file.in
```

This will write all lines between the line containing `08/01/2017` to the one containing `08/15/2017` (inclusive) to the file `first.out`.  Similarly for the second range of dates, but to `second.out`.

This relies on the file `file.in` being sorted in date order.

The `#` character was chosen as the pattern delimiter as the pattern already contains `/`.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest ***awk*** approach:

```
awk -F'[|/]' '{print >(($5<=15)?"1-15":"16-31")"Aug"}' file
```

- `-F'[|/]'` - complex field separator

---

Viewing results:

```
for f in [0-9]*Aug; do echo "file: $f"; cat "$f"; echo; done
```

---

The output:

```
file: 1-15Aug
a|b|c|08/01/2017|d
a|b|c|08/15/2017|d

file: 16-31Aug
a|b|c|08/16/2017|d
a|b|c|08/31/2017|d
```

Comment: (assuming the first 3 fields don't contain `/` characters).

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple `csplit` if your data is sorted by date.

```
split -f abc greptest.txt '/08\/16\/2017.*$/'
```

It will cut your file into two when finding the first Line containing `08/16/2017`. They will be named `abc00` and `abc01`